# Errors when trying to use chemfig

Tags: errors

When trying to use chemfig I get two errors.First there is a "two documentclass" error and second a "undefined control sequence \chemfig".What can be done about this? Uninstall/reinstall doesn't help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Maybe you have put `\documentclass{chemfig}` instead of `\usepackage{chemfig}` to your header.

Comment: Found out whatwas wrong. Turns out that chemfig DOES NOT load tikz.So after inclusion of \usepackage{tikz} in my preamble it worked. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @numicius that's strange because ususally `chemfig` _does_ load TikZ!

Answer (score 4):

I would guess that your main document is called `chemfig.tex` which is a bad idea as `\chemfig.sty` is a thin wrapper which inputs the plain tex macros `chemfig.tex` via

```
\input chemfig.tex
```

so since the current directory of the main document (not of the current file) is usually at the front of the search path, this just re-inputs your main document and you get an error about  two `\documentclass` commands.